# ImageView is not displaying the image src

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying to use the Icon image provided in the `drawable` folder using `imageView` and src attribute but the icon is not being displayed when I run the app and even it's not showing in the emulator.

```
<RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="60dp"
           android:layout_height="60dp"
           android:scaleType="center"
           android:adjustViewBounds="true"
           android:src="@drawable/icon-chat"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I expect the image should be displayed in the `imageview`. Do I need to add any other attributes in the `imageView` ???

Comment: icon_char is a png file downloaded from the internet. I also tried to use my other images inside the drawable folder but still, the emulator is not displaying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is certain naming convention in naming the drawables file, so while naming your files in drawable keep in mind following two points .

> 1)Valid characters for naming resources is [a-z, _, 0–9] .In short all
> small case characters, numbers, and underscore.
>
> 2)First letter of your
> asset(file) name can be either _ or a small case character, it cannot be a
> number.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a '-' in a drawable name. Rename your drawable to 'icon_chat' instead of 'icon-chat'.

```
<ImageView
     android:layout_width="60dp"
     android:layout_height="60dp"
     android:scaleType="center"
     android:adjustViewBounds="true"
     android:src="@drawable/icon_chat"/>
```

Comment: True. But he can't build the apk or check the apk without solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use drawable-nodpi folder in res if image is too big.

Answer (score 0):

Your icon may be of larger size. Copy it to folder drawable-xxhdpi in project explorer then try.